# Are even functions injective?

Tags: functions

[image]

In the above question (example 68) they have solved it by assuming that $$x =\frac{x+1}{x+2}$$ and similarly for $-x$, but to use that the function must be injective right? Otherwise couldn't it be possible that $x$ and $x =\frac{x+1}{x+2}$ are two different values having same image?

Comment: the observation that multiple $x$ have the same image says something about injectivity

Answer (score 2):

Even function are never injective, since for any $x \neq 0$, one has $x \neq -x$ and $f(x)=f(-x)$.

Comment: But then how did they conclude that x= (x+1)÷(x+2)

Comment: The solution of the book is totally wrong. For any constant function, all $x$ (except $x=-2$) are satisfying the equation... I think you should just throw this book :)

Answer (score 1):

The given solution is wrong. For example, $f(x) = 1$ is an even function and in this case every $x$ satisfies the equality except $x=-2$ where the right hand side is not defined.

If they had said "which must satisfy the equation for any even $f$" then the result and the solution given would be true. Injectivity of the restriction of the function to the positive reals would also make their solution correct. The function itself will never be injective, since it's even.

Comment: could you please explain in detail how adding the line "which must sa...... for any even f" makes the answer correct?